# Two dimensional representation of $Q_8$

Tags: representation-theory, quaternions

I am trying to find what this two-dimensional representation of $Q_8$ is. I have deduced its existence from the character table but now I’m trying to  actually see how it works.

I guess I’m looking for some sort of natural way to do this but it seems tricky.

Any pointers?

Comment: Consider $Q_8$ as the group $\{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ inside the quaternions $\mathbb{H} = \mathbb{C}^2$. Then the action of $Q_8$ act on itself by multiplication gives a representation $Q_8 \to GL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: How is $\mathbb{H}$ viewed inside $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Quaternions_as_pairs_of_complex_numbers) on quaternions and $\mathbb C^2$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-character way to find the two dimensional representation for $Q_8$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196835/non-character-way-to-find-the-two-dimensional-representation-for-q-8)

Comment: $Q_8$ embeds in $\mathbb{H}$, and $\mathbb{H} = \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R} i \oplus \mathbb{R}j \oplus \mathbb{R}k = \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}j$.

Comment: @anomaly While you can do it the other way around, I think it is a little more standard (and I would argue for) viewing $\Bbb H=\Bbb C\oplus j\Bbb C$ as a *right* $\Bbb C$-vector space on which $Q_8$ acts from the left.

Comment: @runway44: Sure, I'd agree with that.